# Type deduction fails with pointer to member method

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I have the following template class which acts as a proxy. It has a method named `call` which is supposed to be used to call methods on the wrapped object. There's a problem with it. The type deduction fails and I cannot understand why.

`Hudsucker::f` takes an `std::string` and then no matter if I pass an `std::string` or a `const` reference to it the compiler is able to call the right method.

But in case of `Hudsucker::g` with takes a `const` reference to `std::string` type deduction fails in both cases with both GCC and Clang.

**GCC error for the first line:**

```
main.cpp:36:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘Proxy<Hudsucker>::call(void (Hudsucker::*)(const string&), const string&)’
main.cpp:36:28: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:10:10: note: template<class A> void Proxy::call(void (T::*)(A), A) [with A = A; T = Hudsucker]
main.cpp:10:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:36:28: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘A’ (‘const std::basic_string<char>&’ and ‘std::basic_string<char>’)
```

Especially this bit is strange: `no matching function for call to  Proxy<Hudsucker>::call(void (Hudsucker::*)(const string&), const string&)`. That is exactly the signature I would expect to see work.

**Clang error for the first line:**

```
main.cpp:36:7: error: no matching member function for call to 'call'
    p.call(&Hudsucker::g, s); // <- Compile error
    ~~^~~~
main.cpp:10:10: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'A' ('const std::basic_string<char> &' vs. 'std::basic_string<char>')
    void call(void (T::*f)(A), A a)
```

**Code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class Proxy
{
public:
    Proxy(T &o): o_(o) {}

    template <typename A>
    void call(void (T::*f)(A), A a)
    {
        (o_.*f)(a);
    }

private:
    T &o_;
};

class Hudsucker
{
public:
    void f(std::string s) {}
    void g(std::string const &s) {}
};

int main()
{
    Hudsucker h;
    Proxy<Hudsucker> p(h);
    std::string const s = "For kids, you know.";
    std::string const &r = s;

    p.call(&Hudsucker::f, s);
    p.call(&Hudsucker::f, r);

    p.call(&Hudsucker::g, s); // <- Compile error
    p.call(&Hudsucker::g, r); // <- Compile error

    return 0;
}
```

Could you explain why the type deduction fails in that way? Is there a way to get this to compile with `const` references?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler cannot deduce the type `A`, since it has contrasting information. From the type of the member function, it would deduce `A` to be `std::string const&`, while from the type of the second argument, it would deduce it to be `std::string`.

Change your function template into one that allows different types for the parameter of the member function and the argument actually provided, and then SFINAE-constrain the latter to be convertible to the former:

```
template <typename A, typename B,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<B, A>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void call(void (T::*f)(A), B a)
{
    (o_.*f)(a);
}
```

If you are wondering why from this function call:

```
std::string const s = "For kids, you know.";
// ...
p.call(&Hudsucker::g, s);
```

The compiler would deduce `std::string`, that's because of paragraph 14.8.2.1/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> **If `P` is not a reference type**:
>
> — If `A` is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer standard conversion (4.2) is
>   used in place of `A` for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> — If `A` is a function type, the pointer type produced by the function-to-pointer standard conversion (4.3)
>   is used in place of `A` for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> — **If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `A`’s type are ignored for type deduction**.

In the quoted paragraph, `P` is your `A` (from your function template) and `A` is `std::string const`. This means the `const` in `std::string const` is ignored for type deduction. To see this better, consider this simpler example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    // Does NOT fire!
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value, "!");
}

int main()
{
    int const x = 42;
    foo(x);
}
```

Considering the second function call:

```
std::string const &r = s;
// ...
p.call(&Hudsucker::g, r);
```

The reason is that the type of the *id-expression* `r` is `std::string const`. The reference is dropped because of paragraph 5/5:

> **If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to
>   any further analysis**. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and the
>   expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

And now we're back to the same situation as for the first function call.

---

As pointed out by Mike Vine in the comments, you may want to *perfectly-forward* your second argument when giving it in input to the first (member function) argument during the function call:

```
#include <utility> // For std::forward<>()

template <typename A, typename B,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<B, A>::value>::type* = nullptr>
void call(void (T::*f)(A), B&& a)
{
    (o_.*f)(std::forward<B>(a));
}
```

---

If you cannot afford C++11, then you won't be allowed to use default arguments for template parameters. In that case, you can use the SFINAE-constraint on the return type:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
typename enable_if<is_convertible<B, A>::value>::type 
//       ^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//       But how about these traits?
    call(void (T::*f)(A), B a)
{
    (o_.*f)(a);
}
```

Notice, that `std::enable_if` and `std::is_convertible` are not part of the C++03 Standard Library. Fortunately, Boost has its own version of `enable_if` and `is_convertible`, so:

```
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp>

template <typename T> class Proxy
{
public:
    Proxy(T &o): o_(o) {}

    template <typename A, typename B>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_convertible<B, A>>::type 
        call(void (T::*f)(A), B a)
    {
        (o_.*f)(a);
    }

private:
    T &o_;
};
```

Notice, that `boost::enable_if` accepts as its first template argument a *type* which defines a `value` boolean member, whereas `std::enable_if` accepts a boolean value. The equivalent of `std::enable_if` in Boost is `boost::enable_if_c`.

Comment: I'm no expert here by anymeans, but wouldn't you want to use perfect forwarding here.

Comment: @MikeVine: Yes, indeed that would be appropriate, but in this answer I wanted to provide a working solution with minimal changes, so that the OP could understand what was wrong with his original program (perfect forwarding is an improvement, but does not solve the problem in itself). Anyway, I should probably add this as a note, thank you!

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you want `::type` before the `* = nullptr`

Comment: @AndyProwl, I saw and removed the comment already =) What about the error that GCC gives `no matching function for call to Proxy<Hudsucker>::call(void (Hudsucker::*)(const string&), const string&)`. It shows `const string&` in both places. Strange.

Comment: @detunized: I believe GCC is giving you a wrong diagnostic (although it is right in rejecting the call). Clang is giving you the error message I would expect

Comment: Is there any hope for C++03? I cannot use C++11 features in my code, since I have to support a bunch of outdated compilers.

Comment: @detunized: Yes, you can use Boost. I expanded the answer to cover that :)

Answer (score 4):

Seems to me a simpler solution would be to just exclude one of the two arguments from trying to deduce A, and the second one is the better candidate:

```
template <typename A>
void call(void (T::*f)(A), typename std::identity<A>::type a)
{
    (o_.*f)(a);
}
```

If you don't have `std::identity` in your type traits, use this one:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };
```

Here's why this works: the compiler cannot deduce A from the second argument, since it's just a template parameter to something that a nested type is taken of. Basically, it can't pattern-match any incoming type against something_that_contains_A::type - due to template specialization, it can't reverse-engineer the argument from the definition of the left side. The net result is that the second argument is an "undeduced context". The compiler will not attempt to deduce A from there.

This leaves the first argument as the only place where A can be deduced from. With only one deduction result for A, it is not ambiguous and deduction succeeds. The compiler then proceeds to substitute the deduction result into every place where A was used, including the second argument.

Comment: This actually works with C++03 on a couple of simple examples. I'll have to see if there are any weird corner cases where it fails. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, there is no standard `std::identity` type trait - but it is possible to use `std::common_type` as `std::identity` (or define your own trait as you did)

Comment: Now I need to understand why it works. Could you explain why such a trick helps?

Comment: Thanks for the working solution. But I accepted the other answer because it explains why this is happening. That what I was mostly interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass template argument to template function when calling it in your main.

```
int main()
{
    Hudsucker h;
    Proxy<Hudsucker> p(h);
    std::string const s = "For kids, you know.";
    std::string const &r = s;

    p.call(&Hudsucker::f, s);
    p.call(&Hudsucker::f, r);

    //just add template argument to template function call !!!
    p.call< const std::string & > (&Hudsucker::g, s); // <- NO  Compile error !!!!
    p.call< const std::string & > (&Hudsucker::g, r); // <- NO Compile error !!!**

   return 0;
```

}